# Obtain the AWS API Gateway Usage Plan from the X-API-KEY

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to obtain the corresponding **usage plan** associated with this API token from the X-API-KEY supplied in the Header.

Since the "get_api_key()" receives the "Key identifier" and not the actual "Key Value," the only way I know to overcome this is to list all identifiers, obtain the identifier with the correspondent desired key value, obtain the usage plan from the identifier.

Is there any improved or straightforward way to do this?

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    api_gateway_client = boto3.client('apigateway')

    # Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual API key
    api_key_id = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

    try:
        # Get API key details
        api_key_response = api_gateway_client.get_api_key(apiKeyId=api_key_id, includeValue=False)
        
        # Extract usage plan IDs
        usage_plan_ids = api_key_response['usagePlans']

        # Get details for each usage plan
        for plan_id in usage_plan_ids:
            usage_plan_response = api_gateway_client.get_usage_plan(usagePlanId=plan_id)
            print(usage_plan_response)  # Or process as needed

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'Usage plan details retrieved successfully.'
        }

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': 'Error in retrieving usage plan details.'
        }
```